# FRP vs. State Machine w/ Lenses for Game Loop

Tags: functional-programming, state, reactive-programming, frp

I'm trying to understand the *practical* difference between a FRP graph and a State Machine with lenses- specifically for something like a game loop where the entire state is re-drawn every tick.

Using javascript syntax, the following implementations would both essentially work:

Option 1: State Machine w/ Lenses

```
//Using Sanctuary and partial.lenses (or Ramda) primitives
//Each update takes the state, modifies it with a lens, and returns it

let state = initialValues;
eventSource.addEventListener(update, () => {
  state = S.pipe([
    updateCharacter,
    updateBackground,
  ])
  (state) //the first call has the initial settings

  render(state);
});
```

Option 2: FRP

```
//Using Sodium primitives
//It's possible this isn't the best way to structure it, feel free to advise

cCharacter = sUpdate.accum(initialCharacter, updateCharacter)
cBackground = sUpdate.accum(initialBackground, updateBackground)
cState = cCharacter.lift(cBackground, mergeGameObjects)
cState.listen(render)
```

I see that `Option 1` allows any update to get or set data anywhere in the game state, however all the cells/behaviors in `Option 2` could be adjusted to be of type `GameState` and then the same thing applies. If this were the case, then I'm really confused about the difference since that would then just boil down to:

```
cGameState = sUpdate
  .accum(initialGameState, S.pipe(...updates))
  .listen(render)
```

And then they're really very equivalent...

Another way to achieve that goal would be to store all the Cells in some global reference, and then any other cell could sample them for reading. New updates could be propagated for communicating. That solution also feels quite similar to Option 1 at the end of the day.

**Is there a way to structure the FRP graph in such a way that it offers clear advantages over the event-driven state machine, in this scenario?**

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what your question is, also because you keep changing the second example in your explanatory text.

In any case, the key benefit of the FRP approach — as I see it — is the following: The game state depends on many things, but *they are all listed explicitly on the right-hand side of the definition of `cGameState`*.

In contrast, in the imperative style, you have a global variable `state` which may or may not be changed by code that is *not shown in the snippet* you just presented. For all I know, the next line could be

```
eventSource2.addEventListener(update, () => { state = state + 1; })
```

and the game state suddenly depends on a second event source, a fact that is not apparent from the snippet you showed. This cannot happen in the FRP example: All dependencies of `cGameState` are explicit on the right-hand side. (They may be very complicated, sure, but at least they are explicit.)

Comment: Wow - awesome to get a comment from you! Nearly all my google searches lead me to writeups on reactive banana, and even without understanding Haskell your tutorials are very helpful!

Apologies for the edit - tbh I didn't think anyone would see it in that window due to the low popularity of the "frp" tag.

In terms of my question - StackOverflow probably isn't the right forum for it... I'm more in a sortof whiteboarding place with it and would rather discuss various solutions over a cup of coffee, hehe.

Comment: Fwiw - this comment is very much in the direction of the type of info I'm looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785025/why-should-we-use-behavior-in-frp/26811823#26811823 

For example, if I have a "drag" event or some gesture which is dependent on data over time, the state-machine approach above requires explicitly storing each change in the data structure, whereas the frp approach can be a simpler mapping